# Grails command object validation gives exception instead of errors

Tags: validation, grails, grails-controller

I have command object like this:

```
 @Validateable

class TaCustomerBoardActionCommand {

TaCustomerBoardAction action

static constraints = {
    action casecade: true
}
}
```

and classes in command object below:

```
class TaCustomerBoardAction {

TaCustomerBoard taCustomerBoard
TaapAction taapAction

Date dateCreated // updated by grails
Date lastUpdated // updated by grails

User createdBy
OrgUnit orgUnit

Client client
static belongsTo = [Client]

static constraints = {
}

}
```

and

```
TaapAction {

int id
User createdUser
User responsibleUser
Brand brand
BusinessType businessType
Topic topic
Topic subTopic
String subject
String description
Date targetDate
int progress
String responsible
Client client
static belongsTo = [Client]
OrgUnit orgUnit
Date dateCreated // updated by grails
Date lastUpdated // updated by grails
TaapActionState taapActionState

static constraints = {
    subject nullable: false, size: 1..64
    description nullable: false, size: 1..4000
    responsible nullable: false, size: 1..512
    progress nullable: false
    responsibleUser nullable:false
    brand nullable:false
    businessType nullable:false
    topic nullable:false
    subTopic nullable:false
    targetDate nullable:false
}
```

TaCustomerBoard has similar constraints as above class.
but it gives exception instead of error codes.
Below is controller Post method:

```
    def saveTaCustomerBoardAction(TaCustomerBoardActionCommand cmd){

    if(cmd.validate()){
        taActionPlanningService.saveAction(cmd.action.taapAction)
        cmd.action.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
    [cmd:cmd]
}
```

Stack trace:

> grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred
>   during save():
>       - Field error in object 'de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction' on field 'progress': rejected value [null]; codes
>   [de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.progress.typeMismatch.error,de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.progress.typeMismatch,taapAction.progress.typeMismatch.error,taapAction.progress.typeMismatch,typeMismatch.de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.progress,typeMismatch.progress,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch];
>   arguments [progress]; default message [Data Binding Failed]
>       - Field error in object 'de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction' on field 'description': rejected value [null]; codes
>   [de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description.nullable.error.de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description,de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description.nullable.error.description,de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description.nullable.error.java.lang.String,de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description.nullable.error,taapAction.description.nullable.error.de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description,taapAction.description.nullable.error.description,taapAction.description.nullable.error.java.lang.String,taapAction.description.nullable.error,de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description.nullable.de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description,de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description.nullable.description,de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description.nullable.java.lang.String,de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description.nullable,taapAction.description.nullable.de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description,taapAction.description.nullable.description,taapAction.description.nullable.java.lang.String,taapAction.description.nullable,nullable.de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction.description,nullable.description,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable];
>   arguments [description,class de.idare.move.taap.TaapAction]; default
>   message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] can not be null]

Kindly help me I am stuck with this problem.

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is rather straight forward. Well it would seem, you have provided how things work but not actually provided what is sent. My suggestion is to do a `println params` in the controller action using validation method to see what it is sent / and validated.

You have declared progress as `int` and not `Integer`. This means it can't be nullable. Always use Boolean Integer or whatever the case maybe if something is meant to be nullable. Secondly you have also declared description and progress as nullable false meaning they have to be provided. The error message suggests command sent does not have a progress or description sent to it as part of the validation. This is something you need to investigate further by simple debugging such as println at your end to figure out why that is the case.

```
  int progress
...
 static constraints = {
   progress nullable: false
   description nullable: false, size: 1..4000
 }
```

Comment: params are ok, when I checked `cmd.errors` it shows 0 errors.But on save it gives validation exception.

Comment: I would try creating the Command object within the saveCustomer method yourself, instead of having Grails automagically create it for you. I've found that in some cases Grails can make mistakes doing this. 

    `TaCustomerBoardActionCommand command = new TaCustomerBoardActionCommand()`
   `bindData(command, params, [include: ['abc', 'def']])`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `failOnError: true`. You'll be able to process error objects instead of catching exception.

[Documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html)